# Silverlight- bad mouse position when embedded in html page when Firefox has zoom

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

We have a Silverlight control embedded in an html page.  When I zoom the html page in FireFox 3.5 (ctrl - +) and then try to click on something in the Silverlight control the mouse input is not taken at the correct place.

I have to click above the control to get it.  This behavior can be seen here:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous reports of the issue and some possible fixes.

See these links:

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/227806/614938.aspx

"I decided to try uninstalling and reinstalling firefox and that did the trick."

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/795168

"Enabling the plugin-container.exe in about:config (dom.ipc.plugins.enabled) fixes the mouse issue but then Silverlight plugin pop-ups (webcam/microphone permission for example) freeze the browser."

[Windowless Silverlight (and Flash?) app on Firefox: wrong mouse positions reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236746/windowless-silverlight-and-flash-app-on-firefox-wrong-mouse-positions-report)

"This problem doesn't happen if you do one of the following:

1. Switch Firefox into full screen mode (it seems that the top bar is the cause for the offset, so when it's not visible there is no offset).
2. Do not use Silverlight in a windowless mode.
3. Use any other browser.

...

In my research I came across the following suggested workarounds...:

- Do not use overflow in css.
- Use css to set html margin of 1px.
- Do not use iframe"

Comment: +1 I had this problem too, FF 9 + SL 5 runtime. Fullscreen made the clicks hit the right position. Then after a changing dom.ipc.plugins.enabled and a restart it worked without fullscreen.